# How do the "dfs.replication" and "dfs.datanode.data.dir" configurations work in a cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

I've followed the Apache "Single Node Setup" instructions which sets the `dfs.replication` on the single node.

But then I followed the "Cluster Setup" but it doesn't mention about this property, so I don't know whether this is a property to be set on the Namenode, or also/only on Datanodes ..

I have also read that setting multiple (comma-separated) paths in `dfs.datanode.data.dir` on data nodes will replicate data on all paths.

So my question is : on which node(s) will the `dfs.replication` have an effect, and if multiple paths for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` are set, are these extra independent replications only per Datanode, or are these also tied in some way by the `dfs.replication` factor ?

And also, what is the use this extra local replication on Datanodes when the data is already replicated on other nodes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, first let's see the description for these configuration flags from the [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml):

**Configuration option:** ***dfs.replication***

> Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.

Intuitively, this tells that we can use this option to specify the replication factor for the blocks of data to be stored. This property is pre-configured to be equal to 3.

**Q: Which nodes does it affect?**:

**Answer:** ***From a storage perspective***, it affects datanodes, mainly, because they are the ones storing the blocks. Of course, *technically*, it does affect the Namenode and specifically the ***FsImage*** (File System Image) file that contains all the mappings of Datanodes - Stored Blocks.

***From a ''functionality'' perspective*** it mainly affects namenodes because they are the ones that decide where to store these blocks. The general -default- strategy for this is:

> Hadoop’s   default strategy    is  to  place   the first   replica on  the same    node    as  the client  (for    clients running outside the
>   cluster,    a   node    is  chosen  at  random, although    the system  tries   not to  pick    nodes   that    are too full    or  too busy).  The
>   second  replica is  placed  on  a   different   rack    from    the first   (off-rack), chosen  at  random. The third   replica is  placed  on
>   the same    rack    as  the second, but on  a   different   node    chosen  at  random. Further replicas    are placed  on  random  nodes   in
>   the cluster,    although    the system  tries   to  avoid   placing too many    replicas    on  the same    rack.

In ***single-mode*** and ***pseudo-distributed*** mode this option is set equal to 1 for obvious reasons, you only have one machine. In a multi-machine - ***cluster*** set-up, defaulting to a value of 3 is what is recommended.

**Configuration option:** ***datanode.data.dir***

> Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. **If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices**. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

**Q: Are these extra independent replications only per Datanode, or are these also tied in some way by the** **`dfs.replication`** **factor?**

**Answer:** From what I have read, specifying the `datanode.data.dir` doesn't mean that there are going to be more replications of blocks. It just specifies **the directories**, on the machine running the datanode instance, in which you want to store the blocks.

---

Take a look at this [PDF on HDFS Design](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.pdf). It is better than any answer I could give and it should help you understand these concepts a bit better.